# find out what a syscall parameter is in 'real life'

Tags: assembly

I am looking at a program that uses the mmap syscall with the flag parameter as 0x22. As I am quite a newbie with all this I do not understand **how** I can find out what 0x22 is exactly (as in is it: MAP_PRIVATE or is it MAP_ANON etc.).

Now my question is mostly about how I would find out, not so much what this example means. SO that the next time I can quickly do it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you'd look in the manual (try `man 2 mmap`).  From there on, you would check the header files for the values of the symbol constants defined there to reconstruct what 0x22 might be.  But mostly, read the manual.

Comment: I think I am looking at the manual at: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html. But can you help me in how to go from that manual to what 0x22 would mean? As in there are no byte values in the manual only variable names that you can use in C

Comment: @Wealot In the manual, it says what header files to include for the definitions of the symbolic constants.  Try to find the header files (usually located in `/usr/include`) and read the them to find the definitions of the symbolic constants.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot! I am finally getting somewhere with this :P. One problem though... I cannot find anything 0x22 or 34 in any of the mmap.h files that I have. The rest I do find. Do you know why this is? (I know it is kinda a different question...)

Comment: @Wealot The symbolic constants found in the header are ored into a single constant before before being passed to the system.  What you have to do is find which constants make up the bits that are set in 0x22.

Comment: AH! off course that makes sense! :P Thank you very much